# SSD failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT

Tags: arch-linux, ssd, smartctl

I have a fairly new SSD (516 Power on hours according to SMART) which fails to boot. Windows is installed on the SSD which can't boot (since an update) The disk can't written from an Arch Linux USB stick nor can it be formatted with `gdisk`. Meanwhile I can read files from NTFS on the SSD.

The output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda` is:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SATAFIRM   S11
Serial Number:    50026B76820CB556
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 6820cb556
Firmware Version: SBFK71W1
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 16 21:33:41 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (65535) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x00)     Offline data collection not supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1377
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       516
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       465
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   255   255   000    Old_age   Offline      -       44
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   255   255   000    Old_age   Offline      -       331
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       57
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       13
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       589847
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0000   255   255   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       54
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       135
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   075   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       25 (Min/Max 18/43)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       72
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       2368
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2010
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2774
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       23
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99620

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 417 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 417 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 71 08 d8 67 4a e0  Device Fault; Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004a67d8 = 4876248

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 d8 67 4a e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 416 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 71 08 d8 67 4a e0  Device Fault; Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004a67d8 = 4876248

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 d8 67 4a e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 415 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 71 08 d8 67 4a e0  Device Fault; Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004a67d8 = 4876248

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 d8 67 4a e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 414 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 71 08 d8 67 4a e0  Device Fault; Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004a67d8 = 4876248

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 d8 67 4a e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 413 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 71 08 30 60 4a e0  Device Fault; Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004a6030 = 4874288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 30 60 4a e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:00:00.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      00:00:00.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

An attempt to format the SSD with `gdisk` shows many dmesg errors and has no apparent effect:

```
[ 1177.956851] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1177.958313] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1177.959473] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1177.960651] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 12
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1177.963541] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1177.965261] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1177.967346] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1177.967349] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1177.967356] ata6: EH complete
[ 1177.979805] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1177.981531] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1177.982788] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1177.984465] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 21
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1177.987853] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1177.989537] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1177.991548] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1177.991551] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1177.991555] ata6: EH complete
[ 1178.003135] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1178.004540] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1178.005433] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1178.006327] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 29
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1178.008132] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1178.008969] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1178.009912] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1178.009914] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1178.009915] ata6: EH complete
[ 1178.039790] ata6.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
[ 1178.039792] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1178.040702] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1178.041606] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1178.042507] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 15
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1178.044315] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1178.045217] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1178.046341] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1178.046342] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1178.046344] ata6: EH complete
[ 1178.079794] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1178.081229] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1178.082349] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1178.083471] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 28
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1178.085686] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1178.086782] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1178.088226] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1178.088228] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[ 1178.088231] ata6: EH complete
[ 1178.099797] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1178.100640] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 1178.101469] ata6.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[ 1178.102298] ata6.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 9
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 1178.104278] ata6.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[ 1178.105375] ata6.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1178.107621] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1178.107626] ata6.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
```

I found a few posts on the internet about the `failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT` error but most are about old HDDs and appear to be different.

I have a backup and don't need to recover data from the disk but is it possible to fix the disk and install Arch Linux or Windows again?